# Identification of Bone like subject found on Beach in santa cruz ca

Tags: marine-biology, bone

I found this at the Beach in **Santa Cruz California,** it is **about 2 inches long** and at its widest it is **about 1.5 inches wide** and it **weighs 3 grams,** and I'm not sure what it is, Google Image search suggests a dehydrated ducks Foot, it looks more like a fin from a fish or something or at least part of one. Does anyone have any ideas of what it could be? (All images are of the same subject) 
[image: Image one] 
[image: Image two]
[image: Microscopic view] 
[image: flared end] 
[image: Joint end]